# Azure Active Directory sign-in appearing after successful request in Cypress test?

Tags: azure-active-directory, cypress

In my Cypress tests, the app I am trying to access requires Azure Active Directory for user authentication.
I am trying to by-pass logging in via the UI, & instead log in by sending the below POST request, & then navigating to the URL.

When I run the below code, I am getting a 200 response code from the request, however the pop-up modal requiring me to sign in is still appearing.

[image]

Here is the response body:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
let password = 'myPassword';
let clientId = 'myClientId';
let tenantId = 'myTenantId';

cy.request({
  method: "POST",
  url: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token`,
  form: true,
  body: {
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: password
  },
}).then(response => {
  const ADALToken = response.body.access_token;
  const expiresOn = response.body.expires_on;

  localStorage.setItem("adal.token.keys", `${clientId}|`);
  localStorage.setItem(`adal.access.token.key${clientId}`, ADALToken);
  localStorage.setItem(`adal.expiration.key${clientId}`, expiresOn);
  localStorage.setItem("adal.idtoken", ADALToken);
           
  sessionStorage.setItem('access_token', response.body.access_token);
}).then(() => {
  cy.visit('myWebAppUrl')
});
```

I would have thought getting a 200 response would mean that this pop-up no longer appears as I would have been authenticated.

Is there something that I'm missing from my code? Can someone please tell me how tor resolve this?

Comment: You are using client credentials grant type to get the access token which do not require user interaction. This grant type is mainly used for daemon application where user's interaction is not required, you don't need to bypass logging in that case.

Comment: If your application requires user interaction, then you would require authorization grant flow to get the access token. In that case, you will require to pass credentials to authenticate the user.